# Adobe CS6 problems after installing MacOS 10.12.5

Tags: java

After installing the newest version of Mac OS, I can't open Illustrator at all, and InDesign and Photoshop are giving me a notification that "The Universal Type Client application that is currently running is incompatible with the Universal Type plug-in". I don't know what that means but I guess its related to the fact that Illustrator suddenly isn't working either? I tried updating my version of Java but that didn't help. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: CS6 is neither qualified nor tested for Sierra. Adobe recommends a **minimum** of CC2017 [which is of course also 'maximum']. https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/install-creative-suite-mac-os-sierra.html

Comment: So I guess I have to revert to an older OS in order to use  CS6?

Comment: It would be a whole lot simpler to update Adobe than 'downdate' the OS, but sure, that would be one 'fix'.

Comment: I agree, and I really wish I could update all my apps to CC, but I can't afford it at the moment, so thats why I need a workaround.

Comment: Downgrading the OS needs you to have 1) a clean, untouched since you upgraded, Time Machine backup, & 2) either an existing copy or existing 'purchase' of the chosen OS in your History on the App Store. There is no way to ***just*** revert the OS keeping everything else intact; you must nuke & pave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to update your type management software from Extensis.

Comment: Updating Extensis software actually was the problem. So although they didn't provide steps how to do it (which I got from someone in another forum), the answer is correct.